# Search functionality on nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, search, nested

[image]

The requirement is such, return the `categories name` on the top level if the search value matches with the `dishes name inside dishes array`.

If I search a dishes name here for example if I search `name = veg mulligatawany soup` then it should return the `categories name = Soups`.

[image]
depthSearch return empty array here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add this json as text or at least a part of it.You should also first try to do it yourself and then ask

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried myself, here I've added some extra info.

Comment: Still, adding code as an image isn't enough, it should be added as text, same with this json

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code must not be presented as images.

Comment: Could you please share the solution if you have understood it. If not thank you for your kind feedback I'll try to give more info for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help with this. I may have this question backwards as your question is not formatted very well and I feel I'm lacking some information. Nevertheless, I have a CodePen that may help. This CodePen demonstrates retrieving this information that you asked for. However, I purposefully didn't provide a complete solution. Instead I opted to demonstrate how you would search for the value and return it. It will be up to you to integrate and make this solution work for you.

But, before you take the code, let's learn a thing or two. After all, we all need to learn more and become more effective as developers. Let's begin.

You can refer to this resource as we go: https://medium.com/@jeff_long/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c

You used filter functions in your code sample. (please format as code in the future and not as an image) There are great when you are assigning a new array from an existing array in which you filter the results. For example,

```js
const _arr = ['1', '2', '3']
const _arr2 = _arr.filter(val => val !== '2') // ['1', '3']
```

However, this function returns data and therefore takes up more memory space when executed. This function is useful when you are cloning or creating datasets from another array where you need the data in a new variable.

I used .forEach because this function doesn't return a new object like .filter does. Instead it allows you to do operations on the contents that you are iterating through. For example, you could print out the contents in a console.log statement. Or, you can trigger side effects in your code. Or, in my case, you can compare and set/update variables outside of the scope of your .forEach function. This function results in less memory used typically and lends itself to more performant code.

It seems that you already picked up on making the search non-case-sensitive. That's good! However, you missed lower-casing your search value. Lower-casing this value too will prevent searches such as `'Bacon' === 'bacon' // false`

I have attached the CodePen below as promised. Let me know if this is NOT what you were looking for and I misunderstood the problem. Happy coding!

https://codepen.io/brentvdalling/pen/xxWvbgy?editors=0011

##### // sources that backup my claims

https://gomakethings.com/how-performant-are-modern-array-methods-vs-old-school-for-loops-in-vanilla-js/

https://medium.com/@jeff_long/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c